# Painless method to zoom&pan so that all elements are within drawing area - d3js

Tags: d3.js

I have a neat script to draw for me using d3, but sometimes, when I have lots of data some of my nodes go off the div. I could code something to handle this at the co-ordinates level, I guess, but I can amend this easily using zoom and pan manually and was wondering whether there's a good, simple way to have it done automatically.

I can consider any other solution too.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're talking about a force layout. Are you looking for something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492)?

Comment: Nevermind, I reread your question and noticed that you were talking about something different.

Comment: That's pretty entertaining, but no, that's not the case here. It's not a force layout, it's my own creation out of some lines and circles. http://jsfiddle.net/n3s6P/
If you click the second row second line node you'll see what I mean.

Comment: For that, the answer I've posted should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To zoom/pan automatically, you would need to get the extent of your node positions and calculate the scale and offset accordingly. To get the min/max coordinates, you can simply iterate over your nodes. Once you have these, scale and offset can be calculated as follows.

```
scale = Math.min(width / (maxX - minX), height / (maxY - minY));
```

where `width` and `height` denote the dimensions of the container (i.e. the SVG). Assuming that you're zooming/panning by setting the SVGs `transform` attribute, this is what you would need to do.

```
svg.attr("transform",
  "translate(" + minX*scale + "," + (-minY)*scale + ") scale(" + scale + ")");
```

What this does is compute the scale such that the larger of the x/y dimensions fits into the respective dimension of the container and repositions the container such that the top left corner of the extent of node positions corresponds to the top left corner of the container.

Comment: Hmm, it works until I zoom/pan then it reverts to the original location

Comment: If you're combining that with the zoom behaviour, you need to set it there as well, i.e. `zoom.scale()` and `zoom.translate()`.